# Padding in <li>

Tags: html, css, padding

see jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hKs3e/)

I'm applying `padding-top` to an `li` to try to align the text nearer to the bottom. But it's just making the `li` bigger, even though there seems plenty of room to fit the text.

Any ideas?

```
<ul>
    <li class="padded">x</li>
    <li>x</li>
</ul>​

li {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 2px 0 0;
        float: left;
}

.padded {
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I get the same results in IE7 and Chrome, not checked any other browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The li.padding is growing larger because you have a height of 25px plus a padding-top of 3px.

The you should decrease the height of the li.padding if you want to increase the top-padding, yet have it remain the same height as the plain list item. So to have a 25px high block with 3px padding-top, you should set the height to 22px with a padding of 3px.

```
li {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 2px 0 0;
        float: left;
}

.padded {
    padding-top: 3px;
    height:22px /* original height (25px) minus padding-top (3px) */
    text-align: center;
}
```